# Python error: Not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I am running the following code segment to print a `jasper` report in `OpenERP`

```
prev_open_fiscalyear_ids = fiscalyear_obj.search(cr, uid, [('state', '=', 'draft'), ('date_start', '<', fiscal_date_start)]) # prev_open_fiscalyear_ids gets a list of numbers from this code
cr.execute("SELECT id \
                        FROM account_period \
                        WHERE fiscalyear_id IN %s" , (tuple(prev_open_fiscalyear_ids)))
prev_period_ids = filter(None, map(lambda x:x[0], cr.fetchall()))
```

where `cr` is the database cursor to `PostgreSQL` db and I am getting the following error:

[image: Report Error from Client]

and the server log is

```
[2014-08-06 10:27:47,625][ASCO_ERP] ERROR:web-services:[01]: Exception: not all arguments converted during string formatting
[2014-08-06 10:27:47,626][ASCO_ERP] ERROR:web-services:[02]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2014-08-06 10:27:47,626][ASCO_ERP] ERROR:web-services:[03]:   File "/home/zbeanz/workspace/KIAK/service/web_services.py", line 724, in go
[2014-08-06 10:27:47,626][ASCO_ERP] ERROR:web-services:[04]:     (result, format) = obj.create(cr, uid, ids, datas, context)
[2014-08-06 10:27:47,626][ASCO_ERP] ERROR:web-services:[05]:   File "/home/zbeanz/workspace/KIAK/addons/jasper_reports/jasper_report.py", line 287, in create
[2014-08-06 10:27:47,626][ASCO_ERP] ERROR:web-services:[06]:     data['records'] = d.get( 'records', [] )
[2014-08-06 10:27:47,626][ASCO_ERP] ERROR:web-services:[07]:   File "/home/zbeanz/workspace/KIAK/addons/kiak_tb_report/JasperDataParser.py", line 53, in get
[2014-08-06 10:27:47,626][ASCO_ERP] ERROR:web-services:[08]:     self.generate_records(self.cr, self.uid, self.ids, self.data, self.context) or default_value
[2014-08-06 10:27:47,626][ASCO_ERP] ERROR:web-services:[09]:   File "/home/zbeanz/workspace/KIAK/addons/kiak_tb_report/report/trial_balance_report.py", line 149, in generate_records
[2014-08-06 10:27:47,626][ASCO_ERP] ERROR:web-services:[10]:     WHERE fiscalyear_id IN %s" % (tuple(prev_open_fiscalyear_ids)))
[2014-08-06 10:27:47,626][ASCO_ERP] ERROR:web-services:[11]: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What is the problem associated with the query

Comment: Is it possible that the search query doesn't return any results such that `tuple(prev_open_fiscalyear_ids))` is just an empty tuple?

Comment: Yes, the result is fetched in the next line from the DB cursor as
prev_period_ids = filter(None, map(lambda x:x[0], cr.fetchall()))

Comment: How about `(tuple(prev_open_fiscalyear_ids),)` (notice the comma), does that help?

Comment: @bereal yes, the comma solved the problem. If you put it as an answer I can accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `tuple(prev_open_fiscalyear_ids)` is interpreted as a list of arguments to substitute in the query. That's not what you mean, you want your tuple to be a replacement for the single argument:

```
cr.execute(query, (tuple(prev_open_fiscalyear_ids),))
```

Unless I'm missing something, this should work too:

```
cr.execute(query, (prev_open_fiscalyear_ids,))
```

The comma in the end is because `(x)` is always the same as `x`, while `(x,)` is a tuple with the single element.